Web push opens the samsung internet browser instead the twa app
When I click on a web push notification on an android phone it opens the Samsung internet browser instead of the installed twa app.

How do we reproduce the behavior?
Install TWA app on android with samsung internet default browser
Send a web push from the TWA app
Click on the web push
This is my service-worker.js code:
self.addEventListener('push', (event) => {
    var message = event.data.json();
    event.waitUntil(
        self.registration.showNotification(
            message.title, {
                icon: message.icon,
                body: message.body,
            }
        )
    );
});

self.addEventListener('notificationclick', (event) => {
    event.notification.close();
    const isDevEnvironment = location.hostname === 'localhost';
    var dataUrl;
    if (isDevEnvironment) {
        dataUrl = 'http://localhost:3000';
    } else {
        dataUrl = 'https://flowmd.ngrok.dev/';
    }

    clients.openWindow(dataUrl);
});

I tried also this code for notificationclick event (but client.focus does nothing):
self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function(event) {
    event.notification.close();
    console.log("hello");
    event.waitUntil(
        clients.matchAll({ type: 'window', includeUncontrolled: true }).then(function(clientList) {
            for (var i = 0; i < clientList.length; i++) {
                var client = clientList[i];
                if (client.url === 'https://flowmd.ngrok.dev/' && 'focus' in client) {
                    return client.focus();
                }
            }

            if (clients.openWindow) {
                return clients.openWindow('https://flowmd.ngrok.dev/');
            }
        })
    );
});

In addition the Android manifest of the twa app includes this code for the purpose of deep linking:
    <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <data android:scheme="https"
            android:host="@string/hostName"/>
    </intent-filter>

What do you expect to happen?
I expect the web push to open the TWA and not the Samsung internet browser.
What environment were you using?
I use Galaxy S10, android 12

what is a TWA app?

Opening a URL will cause the default browser on the device to be opened. It happens in this case to be the Samsung browser. If you want the link to be handled by the application you own, then investigate deep linking.

@RoryMcCrossan I don't find information how to use deeplinks inside the service-worker.js, would love your help
